# Rename file based on regex in Gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-rename

Say I have a LESS CSS directory structure like this:

```
less/
    core/
        _main.less
        header.less
        body.less
        footer.less
    contact/
        _main.less
        form.less
        details.less
```

I want to write a Gulp task that will look for the `_main.less` files in each subdirectory of the `less/` dir, pass this to gulp-less and write the output to the `css/` dir like this:

```
css/
    core.css
    contact.css
```

Because `_main.less` includes the other files in it's directory, only the `_main.less` files will have to be parsed, but I want the output file to have the name of the directory it's in.

So far I have this:

```
gulp.src('less/*/*/_main.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
```

But this will create a directory structure like this:

```
css/
    core/
        _main.css
    contact/
        _main.css
```

But that's not what I want. I was thinking to use a regex to match the directory name, get this back in a `matches` var, and rename the file accordingly. Something like this:

```
gulp.src(/less\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)\/_main.less/)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(rename(function(context) {
        context.src.matches[1] + '.css'
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
```

This code is just an example. I can't figure out how to do something like this, or if it's even possible.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You look like you already have this, but maybe didn't see [the `gulp-rename` plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-rename#usage)?

I don't even think you'll need to use a `RegExp`, something like this should work:

```js
var rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    path = require('path'); // node Path

//...

gulp.src('less/**/_main.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(rename(function(filepath) {
        // replace file name to that of the parent directory
        filepath.basename = path.basename(filepath.dirname);
        // remove parent directory from relative path
        filepath.dirname = path.dirname(filepath.dirname);
        // leave extension as-is
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
```